# obtain json result from given prototype

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have some prototype which is given below in the **prototype section** and i want to obtain the result which i had specified in the the **resulted-output** section,i want to use some of the es-6 higher order functionality to obtain a result please help to get the result which i described in the r**esulted output section**

thanks advance

```
**prototype:**
let data = [
    {
        "rooms_id": 27,
        "room_num": 101,
        "catetory" : "king",
        "booking_id": 248,
        "checkin_date": "2018-10-23 10:30:00",
        "checkout_date": "2018-10-24 10:30:00",
        "booking_status": "booked"
    },
    {
        "rooms_id": 27,
        "room_num": 101,
        "catetory" : "king",
        "booking_id": 249,
        "checkin_date": "2018-10-24 11:30:00",
        "checkout_date": "2018-10-25 11:30:00",
        "booking_status": "booked"
    },
    {
        "rooms_id": 30,
        "room_num": 102,
        "catetory" : "king",
        "booking_id": 260,
        "checkin_date": "2018-10-23 11:30:00",
        "checkout_date": "2018-10-25 11:30:00",
        "booking_status": "booked"
    },

    {
        "rooms_id": 31,
        "room_num": 102,
        "catetory" : "queen",
        "booking_id": 245,
        "checkin_date": "2018-10-22 12:30:00",
        "checkout_date": "2018-10-23 12:30:00",
        "booking_status": "vacant"
    },
    {
        "rooms_id": 31,
        "room_num": 102,
        "catetory" : "queen",
        "booking_id": 246,
        "checkin_date": "2018-10-23 12:30:00",
        "checkout_date": "2018-10-24 12:30:00",
        "booking_status": "booked"
    },
 ]



**resulted output:**
{
    "king" : {
        "101" : {
            "2018-10-23 10:30:00" : {
                "rooms_id": 27,
                "room_num": 101,
                "catetory" : "king",
                "booking_id": 248,
                "checkin_date": "2018-10-23 10:30:00",
                "checkout_date": "2018-10-24 10:30:00",
                "booking_status": "booked"
            },
            "2018-10-24 11:30:00" : {
                "rooms_id": 27,
                "room_num": 101,
                "catetory" : "king",
                "booking_id": 249,
                "checkin_date": "2018-10-24 11:30:00",
                "checkout_date": "2018-10-25 11:30:00",
                "booking_status": "booked"
            },
        },
        "102" : {
            "2018-10-23 10:30:00" : {
                "rooms_id": 30,
                "room_num": 102,
                "catetory" : "king",
                "booking_id": 250,
                "checkin_date": "2018-10-23 10:30:00",
                "checkout_date": "2018-10-25 10:30:00",
                "booking_status": "booked"
            }
        }
    },
    "queen" : {
        "101" : {
            "2018-10-22 10:30:00" : {
                "rooms_id": 31,
                "room_num": 105,
                "catetory" : "queen",
                "booking_id": 251,
                "checkin_date": "2018-10-22 10:30:00",
                "checkout_date": "2018-10-23 11:30:00",
                "booking_status": "booked"
            },
            "2018-10-24 11:30:00" : {
                "rooms_id": 31,
                "room_num": 105,
                "catetory" : "queen",
                "booking_id": 252,
                "checkin_date": "2018-10-23 11:30:00",
                "checkout_date": "2018-10-24 12:30:00",
                "booking_status": "booked"
            },
        },

    },
}
```

Comment: Remember to mark answers as correct, if they solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using `lodash/setWith` you can do this

```
const setProperty = require('lodash/setWith'); 

const formatedData = data
  .reduce((acc, cur) => 
    setProperty(acc, `${cur.catetory}.${cur.room_num}.${cur.checkin_date}`, cur, Object)
  , {});
```